# Can "was" be abbreviated as "'s?"

Tags: verbs, contractions, simple-past

Is it possible to write "'s" instead of "was" in a sentence or is completely wrong? 
For example:

> She was at home yersterday.
>   She's at home yesterday.

Answer (score 7):

The apostrophe + s is usually understood to mean a shortened form of *is* or *has*. It would not be understood to represent a different tense of *be*.

> She's at home yesterday.

would be read as

> She is at home yesterday.

which is incorrect.

(of course, the apostrophe can shorten other words as well, such as *have*, but that is not relevant to your question. Thank you, @bib.

Comment: +1 but I would say *has* instead of *have*. The elided form of *have* is *'ve* as in *I've* or *you've*.

Answer (score 0):

No. That would mean 'She is at home yesterday', which is not grammatical.

'Was' does not combine with its subject in the way 'is' does.

It can, however be combined with 'it' to create ''Twas Wednesday morning, when I saw her', to correspond with ''Tis seven o'clock, and he's not here'. (But its a rather old-fashioned way of speaking.)

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't work because it can easily be confused with *is*.

If you look out how 's evolved as an abbreviation of *is* you will see that the strength of the vowel in *is* diminished. However, the vowel in was is still quite strong.

Comment: In colloquial speech, the vowel in _was_ frequently all but disappears, too. There is still at least a hint of the w left, and the pronunciation ends up being something like [ʃiʊz] or [ʃɪʊz]. Not [ʃiz] or [ʃɪz], though, which is what _she is_ -> _she’s_ gives.

Comment: Now that you point out, that's indeed the case. Thanks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Possibly, in some English dialects, one might hear: "Sheez at 'ome yesterday." What say you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I can’t think of any accents where the two would merge _entirely_. The difference between them might be minute (the tenseness or length of the vowel alone, or even the degree of labialness to the [ʃ], caused by the original w), but at least as far as I can think, there would always be _some_ little difference.

Answer (score -1):

Although it would be grammatically incorrect, most readers would understand what you are trying to convey.  I would regard this as acceptable slang, but I wouldn't use it in something serious like an essay.

Comment: I would imagine most people would mentally unpack that sentence as "She is at home yesterday," which would likely cause at least momentary confusion. Most people would ultimately get it, I'm sure, but the construction is ambiguous enough that it should not be used.